ODBC: ERROR [08001] - Trying connect PostgreSQL in Power BI
I tried connect the PostgreSQL database, hosted on Google Cloud, in Power BI, but no success. First, i use the native connection postgresql in power bi, after, tried conection with ODBC, returned an error 08001 "connection to server at ... password authentication failed for user ...". My password ins't wrong, was verified many times. I don't know what's to do. If anybody can helps me.
When i make a connection into the ODBC, its returned connection successful, but in powerbi ins't work
I think that need the npgsqp into the GAC, but I don't know how do it too, i'm rookie in this world of BI and Databases

Sometimes it happens with ODBC, that it has problem with special characters in password such as: + or % as specified here:
https://knowledge.alteryx.com/index/s/article/Defect-ID-DE33560-Error-FATAL-password-authentication-failed-for-user-when-PostgreSQL-or-Greenplum-credentials-contain-special-characters-when-connecting-in-Designer
Try to change your password to avoid these characters and check if it helps.

Thank's for the answer Michael. Probably is this, because i tried to connect in other database and is work. And that database not have these special characters in your password.

Yes, in that case it should be the case. Try to change your password to omit these characters to see whether it helps.
